# Include template implementation cpp file in header file and link confusion

Tags: c++, hyperlink

I was reading an article [An Idiot's Guide to C++ Templates - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268849/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-2) and came to the [Separation of Declaration and Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268849/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-2#Sepr) part.

Now I have three files with their content as follows:

**sample.hpp**

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_HPP
#define SAMPLE_HPP

template <typename T>
void displayValue(T tValue);

#include "sample.cpp"

#endif
```

**sample.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void displayValue(T tValue){
  std::cout<<tValue<<std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "sample.hpp"
int main(void) {
  displayValue(20);
  displayValue(3.14);
  return 0;
}
```

According to the author,

> your project/build now must not add Sample.CPP for compilation process

But instead, when I use:

```
g++ main.cpp sample.cpp -o main
```

It still works!

I think in such a case the object `sample.o` would still contain **NO** code about the template function `displayValue`, and in the `main.o` object, it contains. So in theory there are no errors. But why the author said `must not`?

Comment: Surely the author wasn't talking only about gcc, we really can't say how other compilers will behave on this. If you make it link again something that was linked before there will be errors

Comment: @MaduraAnushanga Yeah, I also notice that  the author was using MSVC compiler. I just need to confirm that there is no harm if we mistakenly add the `sample.cpp` into compilation files and no linkage error would occur. If the author only talking about MSVC, then I guess it is a flaw of this compiler; but I am not sure.

Comment: That will depend on the compiler you are using, author has stated the best practice. I prefer not including cpps in headers, you may have just implemented the function on the header in the first place it will work but maintenance might be problematic.

Comment: @MaduraAnushanga Then I am confused that if more than one translation unit include `sample.hpp` and use the same type, for instance `displayValue(1)` and `displayValue(2)` is called in 2 different cpp files, would there be linkage error since there is 2 definition of `displayValue<int>`?

Comment: Instead of linking it through the header you can link it through cpp or just as well putting the code on the header

Comment: @MaduraAnushanga Would you please clarify it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32647/discussion-between-madura-anushanga-and-hongxu-chen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are partial definitions, so they can be qualified to be "partially" implemented in headers. In your case,

sample.hpp

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_HPP
#define SAMPLE_HPP

#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
void displayValue(T tValue){
  std::cout<<tValue<<std::endl;
}
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "sample.hpp"
int main(void) {
  displayValue(20);
  displayValue(3.14);
  return 0;
}
```

This will work perfectly in any situation, even if you add the header in multiple locations(and is quite readable)

Or else you can still keep what you have done and be "theoretically correct" by including sample.cpp to other cpps that use the template. Which is a bit more work.

N.B: This not the exact answer to the problem but a way to bypass everything including the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that you do not get any error. Because your definition and implementation are regarded  as one file.

Better and usual C++ style is;

Header file (myClass.h):
You should not include the implementation file (compiler will find it if there is any for you).
Implementation (myClass.cpp):
    **#include myClass.h**

Main program (main.cpp)
This will also need **#include myClass.h**

If you implement using this usual style you are expected to get a linkage error only because you shouldn't have separated the definition and implementation of template functions/classes.

Author might be referring to this.

Comment: The author said in the usual separation case, there would be a linkage error since the implementation of function template and the declaration are in two separated translation unit and since there is no instantiation the implementation would actually be discarded. Then the author said that it could be resolved this unusual way. So the author makes a mistake for the `must not` claim?

Comment: most probably. Notice that preprocessor simply replaces **#include** directive with the content of the file. So with that unusual style in fact the author is providing the definition and implementation in the same file.